# Sequelize many to many relationship does not show relationship when using GET REQUEST

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, many-to-many

I am new in the relational database. I am using node js and express for the backend, REST API and database is Postgresql. I am using Sequelize for connection and models. I have created two models, one is a student and another is a course. My goal is One student can have multiple courses and also want to prevent duplicate student name, phone, email. I successfully connect to the database and able to post the request. For course, I post like this, [Image of course post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWrkt.png). From testing the app I am using Postman. But when I am trying to get request from students or courses. **I don't see any relationship between students and the courses**. Here is the visualization [students get request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L3jh.png) and [courses get request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEJOC.png).
**This is the [live code](https://codeshare.io/2KpbzX)**.

**This is my student model**

```
const Student = con.define("student", {
      id: {
        type: sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      name: {
        type: sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      birthday: {
        type: sequelize.DATEONLY,
        allowNull: false
      },
      address: {
        type: sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      zipcode: {
        type: sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
      },
      city: {
        type: sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      phone: {
        type: sequelize.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false
      },

      email: {
        type: sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          isEmail: true
        }
      }
    });
```

**This is course model**

```
const Course = con.define("course", {
  name: { type: sequelize.STRING },
  startdate: { type: sequelize.DATEONLY },
  enddate: { type: sequelize.DATEONLY },
  studentId: { type: sequelize.INTEGER, foreignKey: true }
});
```

**This is my MANY-TO-MANY relationship setup**

```
const StudentCourse = con.define("studentCourses", {
  id: {
    type: sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  courseId: { type: sequelize.INTEGER, foreignKey: true },
  studentId: { type: sequelize.INTEGER, foreignKey: true }
});

Student.belongsToMany(Course, { through: StudentCourse, as: "courses" });
Course.belongsToMany(Student, { through: StudentCourse, as: "students" });

//con.sync({ force: true });

module.exports = { Student, Course, StudentCourse };
```

**This is my REST API SETUP. Student and course post request**

```
//Student post request
    app.post("/students", async (req, res, next) => {
      try {
        const logs = new Student(req.body);
        const entry = await logs.save();
        res.json(entry);
      } catch (error) {
        if (error.name === "ValidationError") {
          res.status(422);
        }
        next(error);
      }
    });


//Course post request 

    app.post("/courses", async (req, res, next) => {
      try {
        const logs = new Course(req.body);
        const entry = await logs.save();
        res.json(entry);
      } catch (error) {
        if (error.name === "ValidationError") {
          res.status(422);
        }
        next(error);
      }
    });
```

***THIS IS THE GET REQUESTS SETUP FOR BOTH END FROM STUDENT AND COURSE WHERE I DON'T SEE THE RESULT**

```
app.get("/student", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await Student.findAll({
      include: {
        model: Course,
        through: StudentCourse,
        as: "courses"
      }
    }).then(docs => {
      res.json(docs);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

app.get("/course", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await Course.findAll({
      include: {
        model: Student,
        through: StudentCourse,
        as: "students"
      }
    }).then(docs => {
      res.json(docs);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems you have some fundamental mistakes here. If the relationship is many-to-many, the Course model shouldn't have any foreign key(studentId), because a course can have **many students**. What studentId would it be, if this course has students 1,2 and 3? Doesn't make sense(unless you work with a NOSQL, then you can have an array of id's as references).

This is where the "junction table" comes into picture, whose sole purpose is to store relationships between the Course and the Student. Remove the studentId column from Course.

Also, i would put autoIncrement:true on the promary keys, because without it you would need to manually create the ID, which is very wrong. Regarding the email, it needs to have unique:true.

I also had to change all types from sequelize[type] to DataTypes[type]. You're not getting any error?

I tested your code(without the wrong column of course), with slight modifications, and the GET routes seem to work(i didn't test the POST, just inserted the records manually into the DB). Are you sure you have records?

Try it without the unnecessary foreign key in the course model. Make sure you have records in the DB(because maybe the problem is in POST, not GET). If it doesn't work, provide more details and code.

Added a picture to show that the GET works for me:
[image]

Edit: The docs of sequelize are very poor in my opinion, and to be honest i don't use this ORM anymore. But this is how i managed to POST a student with a relationship:

```
app.post("/students", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {

      const student = await Student.create(req.body)
      const course = await Course.findOne({where:{id:1}})//Get the course you want to "add" to the user, by id.
      //Notice that here the id hard-coded. You will need to supply it from where-ever..
      await student.addCourse(course)
      res.json(student);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.name === "ValidationError") {
        res.status(422);
      }
      next(error);
    }
  });
```

This route creates a student, and associates it with course of ID 1(assuming this course exists of course).

Note that this is actually really bad: It performs an unnecessary query to fetch a course by its ID, just to be able to use the student.addCourse function. I assume there are better ways to do it with Sequelize, which you will need to explore in the docs, and tutorials. I would personally never do it this way, i would just perform a raw query to the junction table, adding the relationship, relying on both a userId and courseId coming via AJAX, to a separate route, that i would maybe call "addStudentCourse". If you want to know how to do this, let me know.

Again: i find sequelize docs to be so poorly written, that it's better not to use this ORM. Also, learning SQL is very beneficial for one's career. Take that in mind :D

Comment: Hi, 
Thank you so much such a piece of nice advice. I added autoIncrement:true and unique:true .I am really new in this relational database. I have couple of questions to you:
1. If I want to add a student in the course then how I add it. because without student id I can't add them.
2. what part of code need to edit? This is my all code: https://codeshare.io/2KpbzX

PS: YES I CAN STORE THE DATA.

Comment: I sound so stupid to you. How can I post in front-end. For example: I want add courses to the students. This is my app's goal: https://codeshare.io/2KpbzX

Comment: Well man AJAX is a bit beyond of the scope of your question...of course i can write an example code for you, but i think you need to learn the basics on your own- much more beneficial for you. There are really good courses on Udemy for beginners, i can recommend few if you like.

Comment: Sure thing. please send me the link.

Comment: So my problem, there is no easy solution :D

Comment: Well...what is easy? performing an ajax is easy, but the entire UI/UX of that frontend is much more complicated. I don't know what kind of setup you have there. https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-web-developer-zero-to-mastery/ This is the general course. And this is a dedicated node course: https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-nodejs-developer-course-2/ Note that in both, they probably use only NOSQL, because it's easier. You will need to learn SQL somewhere else, if you want.

Comment: Yes sir, Thank you for the effort. Much appreciated.